Nested for loop alternative for comparing a value to the value of previous year for each ID
I have a data frame with 45k+ rows with the values of a variable SE441 by ID NUM_EXPLOTACION and year ANO.
I want to calculate the difference of the variable for every ID between every year and the previous one. The problem is that there are missing years for some ID's, so using the lag function seems not to be the solution for me.
An example of what I want to achieve is this:
ANO  NUM_EXPLOTACION  SE441  diff
2017             657     12    NA
2018             657     15     3
2020             657     13    NA
2018             123      1    NA
2019             123      4     3
2020             123      0    -4

The example data frame:
macro <- data.frame(ANO=c(2017, 2018, 2020, 2018, 2019, 2020),
                    NUM_EXPLOTACION=c(657, 657, 657, 123, 123, 123), 
                    SE441=c(12, 15, 13, 1, 4, 0))

Here's a nested for loop that I believe does the job but it takes way too long, so is not viable to work with:
for (i in min(macro$NUM_EXPLOTACION):max(macro$NUM_EXPLOTACION)) {
  for (j in min(macro$ANO) + 1:max(macro$ANO)) {
    macro$diff[macro$NUM_EXPLOTACION == i & macro$ANO == j] <- 
      if (length(macro$SE441[macro$NUM_EXPLOTACION == i & macro$ANO == j - 1])) {
        macro$SE441[macro$NUM_EXPLOTACION == i & macro$ANO == j] - 
          macro$SE441[macro$NUM_EXPLOTACION == i & macro$ANO == j - 1]
      } else NA
  }
}

In the code above I use min(macro$ANO) + 1 to avoid trying to do the math with non existing values (no previous year before the first one) and if(length(...)) to only execute the function when there is a matching ID and previous year.
Any ideas?

An approach using joins. First joining with completed years, then using diff on SE441 and finally rejoining with the original to remove the missing years
library(dplyr)

full_join(macro, macro %>% 
                   reframe(ANO = min(ANO):max(ANO), .by = NUM_EXPLOTACION), 
    by = c("ANO", "NUM_EXPLOTACION")) %>% 
  arrange(NUM_EXPLOTACION, ANO) %>% 
  mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(SE441)), .by = NUM_EXPLOTACION) %>% 
  right_join(macro, by = c("ANO", "NUM_EXPLOTACION", "SE441"))
   ANO NUM_EXPLOTACION SE441 diff
1 2018             123     1   NA
2 2019             123     4    3
3 2020             123     0   -4
4 2017             657    12   NA
5 2018             657    15    3
6 2020             657    13   NA

Note, leave out the last right_join if you want to keep the completed set of years.
The same approach, using data.table
library(data.table)

setDT(macro)

macro[macro[, .(ANO = min(ANO):max(ANO)), by = NUM_EXPLOTACION], 
  on = .(ANO, NUM_EXPLOTACION)][
    , .(ANO, diff = c(NA, diff(SE441))), by = .(NUM_EXPLOTACION)][
    macro, on = .(ANO, NUM_EXPLOTACION)]
   NUM_EXPLOTACION   ANO  diff SE441
             <num> <int> <num> <num>
1:             657  2017    NA    12
2:             657  2018     3    15
3:             657  2020    NA    13
4:             123  2018    NA     1
5:             123  2019     3     4
6:             123  2020    -4     0


One option is to merge with an expand.grid and calculate diff by group using ave.
> macro |> 
+   merge(expand.grid(ANO=min(macro$ANO):max(macro$ANO),
+                     NUM_EXPLOTACION=unique(macro$NUM_EXPLOTACION)), all=TRUE) |>
+   sort_by(~ NUM_EXPLOTACION + ANO) |>  ## requires R >= 4.4.0
+   transform(diff=ave(SE441, NUM_EXPLOTACION, FUN=\(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
   ANO NUM_EXPLOTACION SE441 diff
1 2017             123    NA   NA
3 2018             123     1   NA
5 2019             123     4    3
7 2020             123     0   -4
2 2017             657    12   NA
4 2018             657    15    3
6 2019             657    NA   NA
8 2020             657    13   NA

If you need something faster, you could try data.table.
> setDT(macro)
> exp_grid <- with(macro, CJ(ANO=min(ANO):max(ANO), 
+                            NUM_EXPLOTACION=unique(NUM_EXPLOTACION)))
> merged_data <- merge(exp_grid, macro, by=c("ANO", "NUM_EXPLOTACION"), all=TRUE)
> merged_data[, diff := SE441 - shift(SE441), by=NUM_EXPLOTACION]
> setorder(merged_data, NUM_EXPLOTACION, ANO)
> merged_data
     ANO NUM_EXPLOTACION SE441  diff
   <int>           <num> <num> <num>
1:  2017             123    NA    NA
2:  2018             123     1    NA
3:  2019             123     4     3
4:  2020             123     0    -4
5:  2017             657    12    NA
6:  2018             657    15     3
7:  2019             657    NA    NA
8:  2020             657    13    NA


Check the desired output, it seems to exclude the missing years.

@AndreWildberg I'm not sure, they're talking about "example", rather cosmetic.

You're right, could also be fine. In any case doesn't hurt to keep them.

@AndreWildberg Could also be useful for subsequent calculations, since it's now balanced in a way.

You could use complete() from tidyr to fill in all the year-id combinations with missing values in SE441, then the lag should work:
macro <- data.frame(ANO=c(2017,2018,2020,2018,2019,2020), 
                    NUM_EXPLOTACION=c(657,657,657,123,123,123), 
                    SE441=c(12,15,13,1,4,0))
library(tidyverse)
macro %>% 
  mutate(orig = 1) %>% 
  complete(ANO, NUM_EXPLOTACION, fill=list(SE441 = NA, orig=0)) %>% 
  arrange(NUM_EXPLOTACION, ANO) %>% 
  group_by(NUM_EXPLOTACION) %>% 
  mutate(diff = SE441-lag(SE441)) %>% 
  filter(orig==1)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Groups:   NUM_EXPLOTACION [2]
#>     ANO NUM_EXPLOTACION SE441  orig  diff
#>   <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2018             123     1     1    NA
#> 2  2019             123     4     1     3
#> 3  2020             123     0     1    -4
#> 4  2017             657    12     1    NA
#> 5  2018             657    15     1     3
#> 6  2020             657    13     1    NA

Created on 2024-05-23 with reprex v2.0.2
